# Basic Calculus Problems.

Tags: calculus, functions

The line $y=1$ cuts the parabola $y=\frac{1}{4}x^2$ at the points $P , Q$. Find the coordinates $P,Q$. Determine the gradients of the tangents at $P,Q$ to the curve $y=\frac{1}{4}x^2$; what is the angle between these tangents?

Okay, my attempt was first differentiating $y=\frac{1}{4}x^2$  but after that I'm not sure what you do, can some one please hint me or guide me through how to do this question please? Thank you.

Comment: First, find the points P and Q. That has nothing to do with differentiation.

Comment: Apparently it does since its in the calculus topic. Related to finding the gradient...

Comment: The problem has to do with calculus. Finding P and Q doesn't. So, I repeat: first, find the points P and Q.

Comment: You repeating " find the points P and Q" is not helping. It's already mentioned in the question what to find. The question im asking you is HOW do i find the points?

Comment: $y=1$ and $y=(1/4)x^2$. Can you work out $x$ from that?

Comment: That is also mentioned in the question above. "The line y=1 cuts the parabola y=14x2 at the points P,Q." Your comments are not helpful as they comment on what given already.

Comment: It says, "Find the coordinates [of] P [and] Q". That's what I'm trying to get you to see how to do.

Comment: Could you just tell me one step, i think that would be more direct and less confusing.

Comment: You are supposed to find the coordinates of P (and Q, but let's do one thing at a time). You don't know the coordinates of P, so let's call the coordinates $(a,b)$. But wait --- P is on the line, $y=1$. That gives you the value of $b$, doesn't it? And P is also on the graph of $y=(1/4)x^2$, so that gives you an equation relating $a$ and $b$, doesn't it? And since you know by now what $b$ is, you can use that equation to work out what $a$ is, right?

Comment: Now I'm going to give you some advice you're not going to like. Drop this course. You are so far behind in algebra, you don't have a snowball's chance of learning calculus. If you don't believe me, go see the teacher, and ask her for advice on what you should be doing, given the problems you are having.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But im learning 1 year ahead of my school, so even if i was struggling with this, im learning. End of the day what you learn is what counts, no matter how much aslong as you take something home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points $P$ and $Q$ are exactly the intersection points of the two curves, $y=1$ and $y=\frac{1}{4}x^2$. Thus, to find these points, you set $1=\frac{1}{4}x^2$ and solve for $x$, which gives $x=\pm 2$. So $P=(2,1)$ and $Q=(-2,1)$.

To find the gradient of the tangent at $P$ and $Q$, you first differentiate $y=f(x)=\frac{1}{4}x^2$, giving $y'=f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$. Thus, at $x=2$, corresponding to point $P$, we have $f'(2)=1$ and at $x=-2$, corresponding to point $Q$, we have $f'(-2)=-1$, which are the gradient of the tangents at $P$ and $Q$, respectively.

Since the slopes are negatives of one another, that is, $1$ and $-1$, the angle between the lines with slope $1$ and $-1$ must be $90$ degrees or $\pi/2$. To see this clearly, draw two lines starting at the origin with slopes $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: It dosent matter. It help me understand better. Thanks Shant

Comment: No problem. If you found it helpful, feel free to upvote or accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First you should plug in the given 'y' into the given equation and solve for x. thus you will have your x values, since x is to the second power, you will obtain two values for x, thus the coordinates (-x,y) (x,y) then plug in those values into the first derivative, for the gradient of each point.

Comment: Ok thanks, ill give it a try.